# how to refresh div and mysql code without reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css

Hey I'm kinda new to this but I'm currently coding a little game and I have a health bar that uses jquery, css and php. I use mysql query to get the value from the database for the health and it works but only when I reload the page. I want the value of the health bar to constantly update for every x amount of second I want it to.

```js
< script >
  function UpdateStats() {
    $.getJSON('demo1.php', function(stats) {
      $('#pbar_innerdiv').animate({
        width: (stats.health) + '%'
      }, 200);
    });

  }, 1000; < /script>
```

```css
#pbar_outerdiv {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}
#pbar_innertext {
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pbar_outerdiv" style="width: 580px; height: 32px; border: 1px solid white; z-index: 1; position: relative; border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;">
  <div id="pbar_innerdiv" style="background-color: maroon; z-index: 2; height: 100%; width: <?php echo $health;?>%;"></div>
  <div id="pbar_innertext" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: white; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
    <?php echo $health;?>/100</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what the php is looking like  
<?php
   $UserStats = mysql_query("SELECT health,hunger,energy,xp FROM stats WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."'");
   $UserStats = mysql_fetch_assoc($UserStats); 
   echo json_encode($UserStats);
?>

Comment: Where is your setTimeout JS function? The ", 1000;" does not make sense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your script like this

```
    < script >
      function UpdateStats() {
        $.getJSON('demo1.php', function(stats) {
          $('#pbar_innerdiv').animate({
            width: (stats.health) + '%'
          }, 200);
        });

         setTimeout(function(){UpdateStats()}, 3000);
      }

  UpdateStats();    

      < /script>
```

This one is better then setinterval it will call second iteration when first one is complete. Hope it will help

`explanation:` first it will call UpdateStats() function after completion of UpdateStats() then it will wait 3 seconds then it will call second iteration. this one will done repeatedly